# Can't uninstall Asus Smart Gesture

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, windows-10-upgrade

I updated to Windows 10, Smart Gesture is not working, can't type without being annoyed with touchpad, can't turn off the touchpad using fn+f9. I downloaded new version for W10 which says I have already installed Smart Gesture, but when I try to uninstall it, it says:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Here's a screenshot of the error message I get:

[image]

I use ASUS ROG G551JK (gaming laptop).

News:
This appeared on my screen.
[image]

Same as when I was installing Windows 10.
Now, it said "installation complete".

Comment: Do you see any number in your error message? Can you try to give us more information about the error you're getting?

Comment: Get back to 8.1, uninstall Smart Gesture, perform the update and install Smart Gesture? I would call that last option.

Comment: @Shimmy I added a screenshot.

Comment: You can download the newest Asus smart gesture driver on asus official site.
I use VivoBook S300CA and it works for me.
http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Smart+Gesture

Comment: " I downloaded new version for W10 which says I have already installed Smart Gesture"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here, for me ccleaner didn't worked, but Revo uninstaller pro did (the trial version).

1) Try uninstall through it, it'll fail

2) Select advanced mode

3) select and delete everything.

4) Install latest version and restart.

edit: I was able to install latest version, but gestures still don't work (double tap to right button, two fingers scroll, etc).

Comment: You could just specify that the advanced mode is in "Scanning mode" option, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my ASUS N56VB laptop. I found that this fixes the problem for me:

1. Remove Smart Gesture with CCleaner (Piriform).
2. After removing Smart Gesture restart.
3. Install the latest version of Smart Gesture from [Asus Support](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Smart+Gesture).
4. Restart and all should be working.

Comment: Remove or uninstall?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - `Uninstall`and `Remove` is one the same operation.

Comment: No it is not. On CCleaner I have options like Uninstall, Repair, Remove

Answer (score 2):

Removing Smart Gesture, restarting and then installing the Win10 version of Smart Gesture resolved the problem.

I did not use CCleaner as suggested above. Instead used regular Windows Add/Remove.

Make sure you know if you are using Win10 64bit or 32bit as ASUS have 2 different versions at the ASUS Support link above,

Comment: I downloaded Win10 64bit. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

OK, Asus N550JA.  Moved to W10,  Smart Gesture stopped working.  Downloaded new version of SG for W10.  Would not install because it saw the old version install.  Could NOT uninstall old version with strange error messages shown above.

Thanks to whoever suggested Revo Pro uninstaller free trial version.  That (using instructions above)  got the old version of SG off.

Installed the new version of SG.  As noted above, it did not work right ....

So, I did a REPAIR on it.  Then it WORKED FINE!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I used the repair option in CC Cleaner for my SmartGesture, rebooted and all of the features seem to work now.

Comment: After repair cursor was blinking, and many other annoying things. Restoring fixed it.